# AWS API gateway body mapping template for dynamodb map

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to figure out how to insert dynamic data into a dynamodb table via an API Gateway in AWS.  Currently I have a dynamodb table and an API endpoint setup that accepts a POST like so.

POST https://{unique-id}.execute-api.us.east-1.amazonaws.com/notification/events

```
{
  "reference_number": 99,
  "purchase_date": "1/1/2017"
}
```

I've setup a body mapping template in the API gateway to massage the data into the dynamodb.

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Events",
    "Item": {
        "reference_number": {
            "N": "$input.path('$.reference_number')"
        },
        "purchase_date": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.purchase_date')"
        }
    }
}
```

The above works and saves to the table.

Suppose I add the event hash to my json (which can change based on events).

```
{
  "reference_number": 99,
  "purchase_date": "1/1/2017",
  "event": {
     "name": "purchase",
     "items": [1,3,6],
     "info": {
       "currencyID": "USD",
       "countryID": "US"
     }
  }
}
```

How do I save the event attribute to a Map in dynamodb using the API Gateway Body mapping template syntax?

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Events",
    "Item": {
        "reference_number": {
            "N": "$input.path('$.reference_number')"
        },
        "purchase_date": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.purchase_date')"
        },
        "event":{
            "M": "$input.path('$.event')"
        }
    }
}
```

The above template gives me the following error.  "Expected map or null"

Comment: Have you tried `"event": { "M": "$input.json('$.event')" }`?

Comment: No luck, I get a serialization exception. "__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like DynamoDB API actually requires the value of an 'M' attribute to be a Map of `String -> AttributeValue`. Unfortunately you can't pass the raw JSON. You'll have to manually map the whole `event` object to make the DDB API happy.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#DDB-Type-AttributeValue-M

One possible workaround would be to stringify the `event` object and write it as type `S` but that would of course require the reader to expect that behavior.

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Events",
    "Item": {
        "reference_number": {
            "N": "$input.path('$.reference_number')"
        },
        "purchase_date": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.purchase_date')"
        },
        "event":{
            "S": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$.event'))"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked this as the solution because it seems the only way to save the event hash using the body mapping template.  I however, ended up using a lambda function to save the event as a map.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you finally did. I reckon the best option is to create a simple lambda function between you API and dynamoDB. Leaving the mapping work up to the aws-sdk.

In that case, the body mapping template in the API gateway would be as simple as this:

```
$input.body
```

And the function won't be much more complicated. I used a javascript function:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var tableName = "tableName";

var saveData = function (data) {

  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: data
  };

  docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  });

};

exports.handler = function (event) {
  try {
    console.log("Processing event: ", event);
    saveData(event);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Processed unsuccessfully", e, e.stack);
  }
};
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html

Answer (score 0):

For my requirement (saving input body), the mapping template is

```
"rawdata": {
            "M": $input.body
        }
```

Note that there are no quotes for input body.

And the data should be in Dynamodb format, for eg

```
{"username":{"S":"Vishnu"}}
```

You could use js lib like [dynamodb-marshaller](https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler) to convert json to Dynamodb format. Hope this helps.