# DynamoDB to 'vanilla' JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm starting out using some of the managed services in AWS. One thing that seems like it should be easy, is to use the API gateway to secure and expose calls to DynamoDB.

I've got this working. However, it seems a little clunky. DynamoDB returns something like this:

```
{
  "id":{"N":"3"}
  // Lots of other fields
}
```

When really I (and most other consumers out there) would like something like this:

```
{
  "id":"3"
  // Lots of other fields
}
```

The way I see it, I've got two options.

1) Add a response mapping field by field in the AWS API UI. This seems laborious and error prone:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
   "Id": "$elem.Id.N"
    // Lots of other fields 
}
```

2) Write a specific lambda between API Gateway and Dynamo that does this mapping. Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231827/2012130 This adds another thing in the mix to maintain.

Is there a better way? Am I missing something? Seems to be so close to awesome.

Comment: Could you please share some code? What language are you using? One way to achieve what you're after is to have a look at the DynamoDB DocumentClient instead, it should perform the way you want.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for that. Essentially I'm recreating the tutorial here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Comment: DocumentClient is the answer.

Comment: The DocumentClient seems like it does what I want. But I'd have to have a lambda in between API and DynamoDB for this to be invoked right?

Comment: Yes of course you'd need a Lambda function to use DocumentClient. The two options you listed in your question (mapping template or Lambda function) are your only two possible solutions. There is no easier/simpler method to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Glad to know that I've not missed an easier option. I suppose hoping there was a --getWithoutTypeInfo was optimistic. Lambdas seem like the best of those two for me. I'm looking forward to doing more with these tools!

Comment: If you don't really want to use Lambda, just handle it in your consumer application. It's easy to do anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
});
```

Comment: this will work within a lambda. This won't work when we use API gateway to directly proxy DDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ODM like dynogels,

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

We use that heavily without dealing with dynamodb syntaxes.
This brings lambda and language in the mix, but it is much easier to handle when an object grows larger to perform the mapping.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option added today. It'll still involve a lambda step, but..

"The Amazon DynamoDB DataMapper for JavaScript is a high-level client for writing and reading structured data to and from DynamoDB, built on top of the AWS SDK for JavaScript."

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-amazon-dynamodb-datamapper-for-javascript-developer-preview/